# AWS CLI combining operators within a single query

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-fsx

I am running an AWS `query` command for `aws fsx describe-file-systems` where I want to combine two operators where it will be looking for `FileSystemType=="LUSTRE"` and another where `Storagecapacity >1200` and then following the another stuff with the query.

In order to get the results I tried below command which came with an error:

```
aws fsx describe-file-systems --query "FileSystems[?FileSystemType=='LUSTRE' && Storagecapacity >1200 ] | reverse(sort_by(@, &LustreConfiguration.PerUnitStorageThroughput))[].{Name:Tags[?Key=='Name']|[0].Value, Storagecapacity:StorageCapacity, FS_ID:FileSystemId,Type:FileSystemType, Mount:LustreConfiguration.MountName, Throughput:LustreConfiguration.PerUnitStorageThroughput, Maintainancewindow:LustreConfiguration.WeeklyMaintenanceStartTime}" --profile demo --output table --no-cli-pager
```

**Error produced by the above command:**

```
Bad value for --query FileSystems[?FileSystemType=='LUSTRE' && Storagecapacity >1200 ] | reverse(sort_by(@, &LustreConfiguration.PerUnitStorageThroughput))[].{Name:Tags[?Key=='Name']|[0].Value, Storagecapacity:StorageCapacity, FS_ID:FileSystemId,Type:FileSystemType, Mount:LustreConfiguration.MountName, Throughput:LustreConfiguration.PerUnitStorageThroughput, Maintainancewindow:LustreConfiguration.WeeklyMaintenanceStartTime}: invalid token: Parse error at column 58, token "1200" (NUMBER), for expression:
"FileSystems[?FileSystemType=='LUSTRE' && Storagecapacity >1200 ] | reverse(sort_by(@, &LustreConfiguration.PerUnitStorageThroughput))[].{Name:Tags[?Key=='Name']|[0].Value, Storagecapacity:StorageCapacity, FS_ID:FileSystemId,Type:FileSystemType, Mount:LustreConfiguration.MountName, Throughput:LustreConfiguration.PerUnitStorageThroughput, Maintainancewindow:LustreConfiguration.WeeklyMaintenanceStartTime}"
                                                           ^
```

**My Own Observation**:
If i should look at the above error it doesn't like the comparison operation with `int` value which I am providing.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have seen your previous thread which is been deleted now, I have posted a tested answer hopefully that should work for you, if that makes sense don't forget to upvote and accept this as an answer :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While working with `json` data type, It's quite obvious that AWS for Linux and macOS you need to interpret strings literally using single quotation marks `' '` to enclose the JSON data structure and get the operator values interpreted. You need to use the command substitution(``).

So, if you use the below command it should work for you...

```
$ aws fsx describe-file-systems --query 'FileSystems[?StorageCapacity >`12000` && FileSystemType==`LUSTRE`]|reverse(sort_by(@, &StorageCapacity))[].{Name:Tags[?Key==`Name`]|[0].Value,FileSystemType: FileSystemType, StorageCapacity: StorageCapacity, FS_ID:FileSystemId, Mount:LustreConfiguration.MountName, Throughput:LustreConfiguration.PerUnitStorageThroughput, Maintainancewindow:LustreConfiguration.WeeklyMaintenanceStartTime}' --profile demo --output table --no-cli-pager
```

Now, if you look at the above syntax, it's very explicit that the complete command body is enclosed within single quotes `''` and the Value against the operators are within the command substitution ``` (``) ``` IE backticks which then correctly expands its value as desired.

**Result:**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                                DescribeFileSystems                                                               |
+----------------------+-----------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------------------------------+------------------+--------------+
|         FS_ID        | FileSystemType  | Maintainancewindow  |   Mount   |                Name                 | StorageCapacity  | Throughput   |
+----------------------+-----------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------------------------------+------------------+--------------+
|  fs-0200c83e16340020c|  LUSTRE         |  3:30:00            |  gjiizbmv |  labdemo-project1-00000001          |  271200          |  50          |
|  fs-067d61e8fts63f99d|  LUSTRE         |  3:30:00            |  s3a3fbmv |  labdemo-project1-00000002          |  249600          |  200         |
|  fs-01dg43bb9455b0011|  LUSTRE         |  3:30:00            |  jg63fbmv |  labdemo-project1-00000003          |  74400           |  50          |
+----------------------+-----------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------------------------------+------------------+--------------+
```